# How to use Spark 1.2.0 in Play 2.2.3 project as it fails with NoSuchMethodError: akka.util.Helpers?

Tags: sbt, apache-spark, playframework-2.2, typesafe-activator

Have you ever had a problem with Play framework? In my case, first of all I have build all in one jar: `spark-assebmly-1.2.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar`, and Spark works perfectly from a shell. But there are two questions:

1. Should I use this assebmled Spark_jar in Play_project and how?? Because I try to move it into the lib_directiry and it  did n`t help to provide any Spark_imports.
2. If I'm defining Spark library like: `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0"`

**PLAY FRAMEWORK CODE**:

**`Build.scala`** :

```scala
val appDependencies = Seq(
        jdbc
        ,"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.2.0"
        ,"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0"
        ,"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.2.0"
```

**`TestEntity.scala`** :

```scala
package models
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import models.SparkMain
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object TestEntity {
 val TestEntityPath = "/home/t/PROD/dict/TestEntity .txt"
 val TestEntitySpark= SparkMain.sc.textFile(TestEntityPath, 4).cache
 val TestEntityData = TestEntitySpark.flatMap(_.split(","))
 def getFive() : Seq[String] = {
                println("TestEntity.getFive")
                TestEntityData.take(5)
                   }
}
```

**`SparkMain.scala`** :

```scala
package models
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{ Seconds, StreamingContext }
import StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf


object SparkMain {
 val driverPort = 8080
 val driverHost = "localhost"
 val conf = new SparkConf(false) // skip loading external settings
 .setMaster("local[4]") // run locally with enough threads
 .setAppName("firstSparkApp")
 .set("spark.logConf", "true")
 .set("spark.driver.port", s"$driverPort")
 .set("spark.driver.host", s"$driverHost")
 .set("spark.akka.logLifecycleEvents", "true")
 val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
}
```

and controller code, which use Spark stuff :

```scala
def test = Action {
    implicit req => {
      val chk = TestEntity.getFive
      Ok("it works")
    }
  }
```

..in runtime a have this errors:

```
[info] o.a.s.SparkContext - Spark configuration:
spark.akka.logLifecycleEvents=true
spark.app.name=firstSparkApp
spark.driver.host=localhost
spark.driver.port=8080
spark.logConf=true
spark.master=local[4]
[warn] o.a.s.u.Utils - Your hostname, uisprk resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface eth0)
[warn] o.a.s.u.Utils - Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
[info] o.a.s.SecurityManager - Changing view acls to: t
[info] o.a.s.SecurityManager - Changing modify acls to: t
[info] o.a.s.SecurityManager - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(t); users with modify permissions: Set(t)
[error] application -

! @6l039e8d5 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/ui] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.util.Helpers$.ConfigOps(Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;)Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:166) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:163) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33) [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185) [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.util.Helpers$.ConfigOps(Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;)Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:314) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:108) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:107) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.util.Helpers$.ConfigOps(Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;)Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;
        at akka.remote.RemoteSettings.<init>(RemoteSettings.scala:48) ~[akka-remote_2.10-2.3.4-spark.jar:na]
        at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.<init>(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:114) ~[akka-remote_2.10-2.3.4-spark.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
```

How to tie the library? through dependency or assembled_jar?
Any advice, please.

Comment: Looks like an incompatible version of the `com.typesafe:config` dependency: `Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.util.Helpers$.ConfigOps(Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;)Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;]]`. Check for version conflicts in your build.

Comment: Is there any reason for using the version not `2.3.7`? I've tried a sample with the version and it worked fine.

Comment: I also found that Akka 2.3.9 made this error go away.

Answer (score 0):

nosuchmethodeersrror exception is 100 % due to mismatch of jars version at compile time and runtime.

check the versions of jar. Also I have some questions about architecture of your app

Instead of calling spark code from play framework you can also call spark submit from shell scripts which looks better in your case. Even you can do it from your play application. no need to include jar in play app classpath.

Comment: I described the problem, of course it is a problem with JAR.

Comment: You propose to use the spark only in shell? No, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the configuration is [Akka](http://akka.io/) dependency of Apache Spark and Play Framework -- they both depend on Akka and, as you've faced it, different and incompatible versions should be resolved at build time with `evicted` command in sbt.

You may want to use `update` command and find the reports in `target/resolution-cache/reports` quite useful.